# Calculate area of a figure extended from the unit square

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, area

I have four points

$$(0,0),\ (0,1),\ (1,1),\ (1,0)$$

and $k$, where $k$ is a number, in this task $k = 1$.

I need to calculate the area of ​​the figure extending it points less than or equal to $k$.

The given answer is $8.141593$ but I don't know how to get it.

Comment: Is a circle inside a square of side =$2?$ Area of a circle radius $1$ is $ 3.141593..$ From where comes 8?

Comment: I don't know, but my figure is rectangle..

Comment: Try to sketch the rectangle.

Comment: https://scontent-waw1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpf1/v/t34.0-12/12476563_1708801162671636_164519159_n.jpg?oh=b23c22dabe3fd924c5de8818a63e8434&oe=56EFAD5F something like this, red line is distance k from figure

Comment: Yor figure is wrong: the surface you are searching for has rounded corners.

Comment: so, I must calculate area of new figure

Comment: Or change the skech

Comment: Knowing the points alone may not be sufficient to calculate the area. You need to have more information about the shape itself.

Comment: This is a contents..

Answer (score 1):

The figure will look something like this:
[image: distance 1 from square]
Here the central square has corners at $(0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (1,1)$, and the outer figure has distance at most $1$ from the central square. Notice how the corners of the outer figure are rounded. It is because each corner is a quarter of a circle with center at the corresponding corner of the square and radius $1$.

To calculate the area of this figure, I suggest dividing it into smaller parts as follows:
[image]

The shapes marked $1$, $2$, $3$, $4$, and $5$ are all squares of side length $1$. As I said above, the shapes marked $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$ are each a quarter of a disc of radius $1$. If you add up these areas, you get the area of the full figure that you are looking for.

Comment: What is the formula for a quarter of a disc?

Comment: I have one more question, What is the situation for the triangle ?

Comment: @JanKo the formula for the area of quarter of a disc is equal to one quarter times the area of a full disc. As for the situation of the triangle, I believe this should be asked in a new question. Remember to include a sketch.